# Need help to set the left to right scrollable using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have designed a page using CSS, HTML and jQuery.

Everything is running fine, but the problem is that left to right scrollable options is visible at the bottom.

What I am thinking is I need to set those things using CSS, which I am not sure if I am able to do.

Top to bottom scrollable is visible, which is required, but left to right scrollable should not be visible.

Only top to bottom scrollable should be there: not left to right.

How I can solve this problem?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Binay_Kumar/stS53/)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Employee Management System</title>
    </head>
    <link href="../CSS/stylenew.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="image">
                <img src="D:\Binay\ISPL Logo\headerlogo.png" alt="logo" />
            </div>
            <div id="codeoverheader">Some company PVT. LTD.</div>
            <div id="codeoverheader1">Home|Logout</div>
        </div>
        <div id="header1"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:header-<length>;
    height:17%;
    background-color:#004080;
}
#header1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:15%;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:2%;
    background-color:#9ABD2B;
}
#image {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:url(../url/headerlogo.png)repeat-x 0 0;
    text-align:left;
}
#codeoverheader {
    left: 1060px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size:25px;
    font-style:oblique;
    color:#0080FF;
}
#codeoverheader1 {
    left: 1200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size:25px;
    font-style:normal;
    color:#0080FF;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any example page.. in jsfiddle

Comment: shall i show my screen ?

Comment: @Cool A screenshot would help, but a demo with [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be even better.

Comment: K fine Mr. @AstroCB give me some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are try to do then the CSS that you need is `overflow-x: hidden;` but you will need to define some widths to make that work. Without your HTML this is only a very generic solution.

```
html {
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This should work for the page as a whole but any specific elements that are too width for the screen may also need to have `overflow-x: hidden;` added.

Comment: i have given the fiddle please check it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for the [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) attribute.

To hide the scrollbar, simply set it to `hidden` in your CSS.

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Be aware, though, that if anything goes off the screen to the right, it will be clipped and not viewable.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/NFx6z/)

Comment: i have given the fiddle please check it

Comment: @Cool Doing what I've suggested removes the scrollbar as you asked, but your demo looks quite strange, and I'm assuming that's because you're referencing local images and stylesheets that the Fiddle doesn't have access to.

Comment: Yes image is not coming ,my problem is in down one scrollable bar is coming ,that i don't want to come.

Comment: @Cool setting the `body`'s `overflow-x` to `hidden` should fix that.